# How to detect numbers with 7 digits in iMacros

Tags: numbers, find, imacros, digits

I have a text area with content, I want tho bot **check** if there was any **number**(s) with more than **6 digits** , then remove it or replace with specific text.

Thank you for time

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
' here your TAG POS=... TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=... ATTR=... EXTRACT=TXT

SET txtToReplace "New specific text"
SET digits 7
SET regExp /\d{
ADD regExp {{digits}},}/
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match({{regExp}}) ? '{{txtToReplace}}' : '{{!EXTRACT}}';")

' here your TAG POS=... TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=... ATTR=... CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
```